# Stuck on computing limit of $\frac{2-t+\sin(t)}{t+\cos(t)}$ as $t\to -\infty$

Tags: limits

Stuck on computing limit of $\frac{2-t+\sin(t)}{t+\cos(t)}$ as $t\to -\infty$

Is there a hint that I can consider to solving this limit?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: try standard techniques like L'Hospital or series.

Comment: Have you tried dividing numerator and denominator by $t$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{t\to-\infty}\left(\frac{2-t+\sin \left(t\right)}{t+\cos \left(t\right)}\right)=\lim _{t\to -\infty }\left(\frac{\frac{2}{t}-1+\frac{\sin \left(t\right)}{t}}{1+\frac{\cos \left(t\right)}{t}}\right)$$
Hence,
$$=\frac{\lim_{t\to -\infty }\left(\frac{2}{t}-1+\frac{\sin \left(t\right)}{t}\right)}{\lim _{t\to -\infty}\left(1+\frac{\cos \left(t\right)}{t}\right)}=-1$$

You can observe that $2/t \to 0$, and $\sin t/t\to 0$ is the ratio between a limited function and an "infinitesima" function: therefore tends to $0$.

Similarly for $$\lim _{t\to -\infty}\left(1+\frac{\cos \left(t\right)}{t}\right)=1$$
Therefore,
$$\lim _{t\to-\infty}\left(\frac{2-t+\sin \left(t\right)}{t+\cos \left(t\right)}\right)=-1$$

Comment: Thank you Sebastiano.

Comment: @Deadpool36701 I'm glady to help you .